# Why Does Azure Require Write Permission On Source SQL Instance During Point In Time Restore?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

I am trying to clone a SQL database from a managed instance to another managed instance. And I am using Point In Time Restore to do so. The identity used to perform this action has "`Reader`" role for the instance of source database and "`Contributor`" role for the instance of the target database.

However, I am getting the following error:

> The client `{...}` with object id `{...}` has permission to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/write' on scope `{target instance}` however, it
> does not have permission to perform action
> 'Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances/databases/write' on the linked
> scope(s) `{source instance}` or the linked scope(s) are invalid.

Why would it need `write` permission on the source instance?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Higher level permissions are required to prevent data exfiltration. Typically, R/O permission is considered a very low level, given for reporting, etc., whereases R/W permissions are given to more carefully selected individuals. Therefore, this is to prevent someone with super-low permissions to be able to copy an entire database over. This is a typical design pattern for all data movement operations, to require higher permissions on the source, implicitly requiring more trust to such user. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but I totally disagree with the reasoning. This forces admins to grant write permission on the source for just a restore operation and this is much more dangerous I think. I hope MS will reconsider this.